# How to stop fancybox hyperlinks from opening in a new tab or window?

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a serious problem about Fancybox. I have a website with an image gallery. Users can report images if there is any abusing data on the image.

At the moment I am using Fancybox to display the report form. I am validating the input fields with jQuery and submit data with AJAX and the scripts are on the parent page.

`<a href="linktothereportform?id=5" class="report fancybox.ajax" rel="nofollow" style="color:#CC0033;">report</a>`

This works perfectly. But if the user opens the link in new tab or new window, a problem arises because the validation scripts are not on the report form. Those are on the parent page.

So is there any way to **stop right clicking or clicking mouse scroll** or how will I overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use a onclick event on a div or button element and invoke fancybox manually through the function call?

Comment: @Scuzzy sorry friend i didn't get you.

Comment: As fancybox requests the form via ajax, you could check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` variable to see if the page was requested via ajax, and if not stop it from displaying the form.

Comment: @vinu please see my answer for a working explanation.

Comment: @Jeemusu Ooops that make sense.:)) i will try and let you know my firend. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to catch all mouse buttons (left, right and wheel) when clicking over the selector `.report` and trigger fancybox if any like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".report").on('mousedown', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 1 || e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).fancybox({
                // API options
            }).click();
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cz29F/)** and try any mouse button over the thumbnails.

**NOTE**: `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Ahaaaa that is great..:)) This is great even for my Fancybox images.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke fancybox via the function call on a div or input.button element

```
<input type="button" value="click here" class="fake-fancy" data-href="linktothereportform?id=5">

<span class="fake-fancy" data-href="linktothereportform?id=5">Report</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('.fake-fancy').click(function(){
    jQuery.fancybox.open({
      href: jQuery(this).attr('data-href'),
      type: 'ajax'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you could actually do `jQuery(this).data('href')` instead of `jQuery(this).attr('data-href')`

Comment: @JFK neat, I did not know that function existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can void the right click and middle click options by replacing all such links with buttons.

i.e.

```
$('a.report').replaceWith('<button onclick="window.location.href=\'linktothereportform?id=5\'">report</button>');
```

You may need to tweak the above a bit, plus style the buttons to look like links etc. but the general idea is to get the 'open-in-same-window' functionality while voiding all 'open-in-new-window' possibilities.

Comment: okay got the idea.As for your answer how would this be possible for dynamic id's?

Comment: jQuery('a.report').each(function(){jQuery(this).replaceWith('<button onclick="window.location.href=\'' + jQuery(this).attr('href') + '\'">report</button>');});

Answer (score 0):

**All the credit should got to the people who gave their correct valuable answers for my question.**

I decided to make a good answer for people who will seek answers for this question in future.

I would basically divide my answer into two section.

As for my original question I needed a solution with hyperlinks.

**So the first method is hyperlinks**

> As @Jeemusu’s comment.

Fancybox use AJAX to load content. There's an HTTP variable set called `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`, which will be set and set to `'xmlhttprequest'`  if it's an AJAX request.

So even someone opens the links in new tab we can check whether it is `AJAX` or `non-AJAX` and display content according to that. So no worries about right clicking.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
//this is an ajax request. do what you need to 
}
else {
    //this is non ajax. do what you need
}
?>
```

**Second option is to change the hyperlinks as a button or any div.**

General idea is to get the `'open-in-same-window'` functionality while voiding all `'open-in-new-window'` possibilities.

> As @Scuzzy’s and @techfoobar’s  answers

```
<input type="button" value="click here" class="fake-fancy" data-href="linktothereportform?id=5">

<span class="fake-fancy" data-href="linktothereportform?id=5">Report</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('.fake-fancy').click(function(){
    jQuery.fancybox.open({
      href: jQuery(this).attr('data-href'),
      type: 'ajax'
    });
  });
</script>
```

**OR**

```
jQuery('a.report').each(function(){jQuery(this).replaceWith('<button onclick="window.location.href=\'' + jQuery(this).attr('href') + '\'">report</button>');});
```

Comment: @Scuzzy,Jeemusu,techfoobar Thanks for your answers since all of your answers are correct i upvoted all your answers and for future purpose i made a complete answer from your given answers. So all the credits will go to you. Thanks

Comment: you can replace `jQuery(this).attr('data-href')` by `jQuery(this).data('href')`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that `link` by a `button` which will not let the user to open that in new tab. You can do it like this :

```
<button onclick="window.location='linktothereportform?id=5';" class="report fancybox.ajax" style="color:#CC0033;">report</button>
```